# Windows batch - WMIC uninstall a software

Tags: batch-file, uninstallation

today i try to create a script for uninstall a software list

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set list='{3B7E914A-93D5-4A29-92BB-AF8C3F66C431}' '{AEE363B0-7E60-43B7-8CB9-111ED29E68CD}'
rem list  = 'skype' 'jabber'
for %%a in (!list!) do (
set process=%%a
echo -----------------------------
echo var = %%a
echo.
wmic product where "identifyingnumber like %%a " call uninstall /nointeractive
echo ----------------------------- 
)
endlocal
```

my script make the job but he i think my command is dangerous if two software have the same or similar identifyingnumber.

How to uninstall the specific key without use "like" ?

```
wmic product where "identifyingnumber like %%a " call uninstall
```

thx and
sorry for my english .. im french

Comment: `wmic product where "identifyingnumber = %%a" call uninstall` ?

Answer (score 1):

I see no need for the delayed expansion, and setting/echoing inside the loop also seems unnecessary

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "list={3B7E914A-93D5-4A29-92BB-AF8C3F66C431} {AEE363B0-7E60-43B7-8CB9-111ED29E68CD}"
For %%A In (%list%) Do WMIC Product Where "IdentifyingNumber='%%A'" Call Uninstall
```

I haven't added your provided switch to uninstall, because I have no idea if it is correct. Feel free to add it if you are sure it works for those applications.